# Bset way to do customized user layouts

Tags: php, html, css, layout

Hi i am working on a SaaS project and i have a default user layout. I want to offer customized layouts to some people but dont want to end up with 100's of layout files to maintain. Anyone got any ideas on a good way to do this?

Comment: You are asking something too broad. How much freedom will each user have on layout? What do you want to customize?

Comment: Just looking for ideas as a starting point.

Comment: You may build content areas and let users define how the content will be presented. These content areas could be unique configured by each user in a diferent way.

Answer (score 1):

Your you could try creating modular positions and allow users to customize the information of each place. The modules could still also be selectable patterns or customizable. That would be quite flexible in general.

To give any other ideas, I need to know how you organize the information.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Symfony has a nice templating engine, and a ACL. It is a nice starting point for your user custom pages layout for sure.

Take a lookt at its cookbooks: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/index.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/index.html